# MM/DD/YYYY Date to variable conversion m,d, and y

Tags: python, date, datetime

I am struggling to find the best way to convert the date input given by the user as mm/dd/yyyy to 3 variables. I am unable to split this because I receive an error since it is a 'float'.

```
>>> date=3/2/2016
>>> date.split('/')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#152>", line 1, in <module> date.split('/')
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'
```

what do I need to add to this to make sure it doesn't evaluate the date with division?

```
def main():
    date=input("Enter date mm/dd/yyyy: ")
```

I want the input date given as mm/dd/yyyy, and then a way to convert this to 3 variables as m=month d=day y=year

What's the best way to do this?

Comment: I don't understand your input data or your error message. Please provide a sample.

Comment: >>> date=3/2/2016
>>> date.split('/')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#152>", line 1, in <module>
    date.split('/')
AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'
>>>

Comment: i believe it should be

date='3/2/2016'

The problem is that python is doing divides and creating the float 0.000744047619047619 instead of inputting as a string

Comment: def main():
    date=input("Enter date mm/dd/yyyy: ")

Comment: what do I need to add to this to make sure it doesn't evaluate the date with division?

Comment: You need to learn about [the differences between the basic data types in Python (notably, strings and numbers)](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/introduction.html#using-python-as-a-calculator).

Answer (score 2):

Try [str.**split**](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
>>> test_date = "05/12/2016"
>>> month, day, year = test_date.split('/')
>>> print(f"Month = {month}, Day = {day}, Year = {year}")
Month = 05, Day = 12, Year = 2016
```

Answer (score 0):

I wrote this following piece of code and it works perfectly fine.

```
>>> date='3/2/2016'
>>> new=date.split('/')
>>> new
['3', '2', '2016']
>>> 
>>> m,d,year=new
>>> m
'3'
>>> d
'2'
>>> year
'2016'
>>>
```

Like Jessica Smith has already pointed it out, date=3/2/2016 evaluates expressions and divides the numbers. It has to be of string string type to be split.

Answer (score 0):

The error *"'float' object has no attribute 'split'"* suggests that `type(date) == float` in your example that implies that you are trying to run Python 3 code using Python 2 interpreter where `input()` evaluates its input as a Python expression instead of returning it as a string.

To get the date as a string on Python 2, use `raw_input()` instead of `input()`:

```
date_string = raw_input("Enter date mm/dd/yyyy: ")
```

To make it work on both Python 2 and 3, add at the top of your script:

```
try: # make input() and raw_input() to be synonyms
    input = raw_input
except NameError: # Python 3
    raw_input = input
```

If you need the old Python 2 `input()` behavior; you could call `eval()` explicitly.

To validate the input date, you could [use `datetime.strptime()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/datetime.html#strftime-strptime-behavior) and catch `ValueError`:

```
from datetime import datetime

try:
    d = datetime.strptime(date_string, '%m/%d/%Y')
except ValueError:
    print('wrong date string: {!r}'.format(date_string))
```

`.strptime()` guarantees that the input date is valid otherwise `ValueError` is raised. On success, `d.year`, `d.month`, `d.day` work as expected.

Putting it all together (not tested):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
from datetime import datetime

try: # make input() and raw_input() to be synonyms
    input = raw_input
except NameError: # Python 3
    raw_input = input

while True: # until a valid date is given
    date_string = raw_input("Enter date mm/dd/yyyy: ") 
    try:
        d = datetime.strptime(date_string, '%m/%d/%Y')
    except ValueError: # invalid date
        print('wrong date string: {!r}'.format(date_string))
    else: # valid date
        break 

# use the datetime object here
print("Year: {date.year}, Month: {date.month}, Day: {date.day}".format(date=d))
```

See [Asking the user for input until they give a valid response](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23294658/4279).

You could use `.split('/')` instead of `.strptime()` if you must:

```
month, day, year = map(int, date_string.split('/'))
```

It doesn't validate whether the values form a valid date in the Gregorian calendar.

Answer (score -1):

**Try:**

```
def main():
    month, day, year = [int(x) for x in raw_input("Enter date mm/dd/yyyy: ").split('/')]
    print "Month: {}\n".format(month), "Day: {}\n".format(day), "Year: {}".format(year)

main()
```

**Output:**

```
Enter date mm/dd/yyyy: 03/09/1987
Month: 3
Day: 9
Year: 1987
```